# X509 signature->parameter... What does it mean?

Tags: c++, openssl, x509, pki

I'm working in create an X509 certificate signed by a 3rd party API (not using x509_sign())... So far my tool is working... In order to test my tool, I have the pkey that the 3rd party uses to sign, so I generate two certificates, one signed locally and one signed with the 3rd API.

My only problem is this:

```
certificate->cert_info->signature->parameter = certificate2->cert_info->signature->parameter;
```

`certificate` is the one that i'm signing remotely (3rd party API), and

`certificate2` contains the same info but is signed by the same private key (local pkey in pem format)

My question is, what does signature->parameter means?? Debugging the `certificate2` I realized that the type is always 5 and in values doesn't have anything.

Do you know how I can create an object of this type in order to fill the parameter value??

Best Regards

Comment: The signature parameter(s) vary depending on the signature algorithm chosen for the certificate. Different algorithms require different parameters (thankfully the most frequently used require none). I'm *guessing* your certificate is using `sha-1withRSAEncryption` for your signature algorithm (easily the most commonly used). if so, the signature parameter(s) is simply ASN.1 type `NULL`. (that, btw, is where you get your `5` from; the ASN.1 encoding for NULL uses type=5,length=0).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, actually I'm using Sha256withrsaencryption,  do you know how to create an object from this parameter?? Because Is an Asn1_item and I can put it the 5 hard-coded but I wanted be sure that always will be 5 for example if Ibuse this algorithm (Sha256rsa)

Comment: Per RFC 5754, if you utilize the algorithm sha256WithRSAEncryption and specify as such by its OID, the correct value for parameters is ASN.1 NULL (i.e. type 5, length 0). Hope that helps.